# FORM Submit button not working in php

Tags: php, html, forms

code is working properly. When it times to press the submit button it didn't give any answer or error. I'd also tried to change the form< action="..." > and place the result in another file but it didn't show anything.

```
<form action= "" methods="post">
<!-- image section start from here -->
  <div class="desc"> E-LN3465 <br/> PRICE: 5000 Pkr <br/><input type="text" name="E-LN3465"  value="1" /> </div>

  <div class="desc">E-LN7645 <br/> PRICE: 4000 Pkr <br/><input type="text" name="E-LN7645"  value="1" /></div>

 <div class="desc">E-LN7644 <br/> PRICE: 5000 Pkr<br/><input type="text" name="E-LN7644"  value="1" /></div>

  <div class="desc">E-LN3456 <br/> PRICE: 8000 Pkr <br/><input type="text" name="E-LN3456"  value="1" /> </div>

  <div class="desc">E-LN7863 <br/> PRICE: 4900 Pkr <br/><input type="text" name="E-LN7863"  value="1" /></div>


  <div class="desc">E-LN6709 <br/> PRICE: 5000 Pkr<br/><input type="text" name="E-LN6709"  value="1" /> </div>



                <p><input type="submit"  name=" submit" value="Add to cart" /></p>
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            { echo $_POST['E-LN6709'];  }
?>


</form>
```

Comment: Use `method="post"` (without the `s` in `method`).

Comment: also, <input type="text" name="E-LN6709"  value="1" / needs a > on the end

Comment: Could you please let the people - who spend their valuable time diagnosing your problem - know the latest status of your situation?

Comment: No form control should be named "submit" since it shadows the form's submit method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**N.B.:** Making this as a community wiki. I feel there should be no personal gain from this answer.

As outlined in comments:

- Use `method="post"` (without the `s` in `method`). – D4V1D
- also, `<input type="text" name="E-LN6709" value="1" /` needs a `>` on the end – Adam

But this one I caught after:

`name=" submit"`

Your conditional statement will fail because of the space in there.

- Remove it `name="submit"`

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: it's now working when i changed post to get. i don't know how it is working when i changed it to get.

Comment: @RobG I simply used their input name; it could have been named Larry, Curly or Moe, but not Fred.